# Proving that $(T S^n) \times \mathbb R$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n\times \mathbb R^{n+1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm asked to show a diffeomorphism $\psi$ between  $(T S^n) \times \mathbb R$ and $S^n\times \mathbb R^{n+1}$.

I'm not sure on how to proceed here. I have written down $(T S^n) \times \mathbb R$ and $S^n\times \mathbb R^{n+1}$ as

$$(T S^n) \times \mathbb R= \big\{ (x, v, r): x\in S^n, v\in x^\perp, r\in \mathbb R \big\}, $$ 
$$S^n\times \mathbb R^{n+1}= \big\{ (x, w): x\in S^n, w\in  \mathbb R^{n+1} \big\} $$

Can you help me in finding such diffeomorphism?

Comment: **HINT**: Think about the normal bundle of $S^n$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.